# ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, gulp

npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /Users/App/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
>   node-gyp rebuild

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node

ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [Release/validation.node] Error 1

gyp ERR! build error

gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-

gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)

gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)

gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:200:12)

gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0

gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

gyp ERR! cwd /Users/xat_massacre/workspace/chenrui/node_modules/browser-
sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate

gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.0

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3

gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: when i try to run "npm install" to install dependences, i got there errors.

Comment: and you are running... windows, osx, linux?  Assuming you are using osx, did you install command line tools for xcode?

Comment: yeah, i'm using osx and command line tools have been installed. actually, this happened after i installed the command line tools. before installation i got no problem. but now, i uninstalled it, the error still live.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40653 maybe is related

Comment: thank you very much. even i don't know the reason, but it really helped. i use "$ cd /usr/local/lib
$ sudo ln -s ../../lib/libSystem.B.dylib libgcc_s.10.5.dylib" to solve.

Comment: glad to read that :)